# A question about weak lower semicontinuity

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ be a bounded domain and $u , u_j \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $u_j \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^{1}(\Omega)$
$$
F_{1}(u) = \int_{\{ u > 0\}} \dfrac{1}{2}\langle A_1 \nabla u,  \nabla u \rangle +\int_{\{ u \le 0\}}\ \dfrac{1}{2}\langle A_2 \nabla u,  \nabla u \rangle  
$$
and
\begin{equation}
F_2(u)= \int_{\{ u>0\}} f^{+}u dx + \int_{\{ u \le 0\}} f^{-}u dx
\end{equation}
where $ f^{+}(x), f^{-}(x) \in L^{2^{*}}(\Omega) $ with $ 2^{*} = 2n / (n-2)$ and the matrices $A_1, A_2$ are  $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for some 
 $0 \ < \alpha \ < 1$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\lambda \le \langle A_1 (x) \xi, \xi \rangle ,\langle A_2(x)\xi, \xi \rangle \le \Lambda
\end{equation}
for constants $\lambda, \Lambda$.

I don't know if
\begin{equation}
F_i(u) \le \liminf_{j} F_i (u_j) \quad i=1,2. 
\end{equation}

Comment: What is a Hölder continuous matrix?

Comment: If the domain $\Omega$ is reasonable (a $W^{1,2}$ extension domain) then weak convergence in $W^{1,2}$ implies **strong** convergence in $L^2$, which yields $F_2(u_j)\to F_2(u)$.

Comment: @Davide: $A_1$ and $A_2$ are matrix-valued Hölder continuous functions, I guess.